# chartboost.showinterstitial() is not showing ads sometimes

Tags: java, android, ads, chartboost

My chartboost code

```
 mChartboost = Chartboost.sharedChartboost();
   String appId = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
   String appSignature = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
   this.mChartboost.onCreate(this,appId,appSignature, null);
   this.mChartboost.startSession();



   this.mChartboost.onStart(this);
   this.mChartboost.startSession();
   this.mChartboost.showInterstitial();
```

My ads display sometimes...What could be the reason... Please help me out

Comment: you need to pass placement string like this `showInterstitial(location);` configure this placement in ChartBoost dashboard

Comment: could u plesase elaborate on this.. i didnt get u properly

Comment: with the above code chartboost is seen ..but it shows only for 3-4 times in my app and stops permanently after that

Comment: please check dashboard you will know what is place in that.

Comment: we are still not getting you..could u please explain?